# Automatically updating and persisting line charts to the current date in realtime

Tags: javascript, charts, real-time

Am trying to build a monitoring system, which monitors users activity and behavior, and graphically represent data in a line chart in real time. 
Currently am able to update the chart in real time using web sockets when new data is received from the server.

**Challenge**

1. I want to be able to automatically update the chart to the current date/time(Next day) even when there is no user data received from the server.
2. Persisting data to avoid reverting user back to the previous day on the chart

**Scenario**

Last user activity was **20 Mar**, therefore the data shows up to **20 Mar** on the chart but when the current date changes to **21 Mar** i want the chart to automatically update to 21 i.e. with **{x: Mar 21 y: 0}** and further update **{y}** when data is received from the server on the same day  and since the update for such scenario will be made on the client side i want to know how to persist such data i.e **{x: Mar 21 y: 0}** on client side to avoid reverting to the previous day on page reload

**sample code (non-persistent)**

```
let lastDate = current day;
let data = []

function getNextDay(baseval) {
  var newDate = baseval + 86400000;
  lastDate = newDate;
  data.push({
    x: newDate,
    y: 0
  })
}

// calling getNextday function

 updateToNextDay() {
      window.setInterval(() => {
        getNextDay(lastDate)
        this.$refs.realtimeChart.updateSeries([{
          data: data
        }])
      }, 86400000)
```

The code above automatically pushes to the next date **x: newDate** and **y:0** to data and the chart is updated accordlingly at the setTimeInterval. But it can be seen this data will be lost right after a user reloads the page.

**My thoughts**

Am thinking of using localstorage to persist data in the browser

**Finally**

i want to know how to go about such scenario in my instance

thanks.

Comment: If date > current date, change date. Interval's to check the current date periodically.

Comment: Alright get that.. thanks

Comment: @Raymond can you give a short snippet